# PL/SQL - column value is updated as 0 instead of numeric value

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sql-update

```
Declare
v_cnt varchar2(20); 
v_cnd varchar2(20);
v_total varchar2(20);

begin

select count(emp_id) into v_cnt from emp1;
select count(emp_id) into v_cnd from emp2;
v_total:=v_cnt+v_cnd;

dbms_output.put_line('before');
dbms_output.put_line(v_total);

update emp3 set total_emp=v_total where dept_no=40;
commit;

dbms_output.put_line('after');
dbms_output.put_line(v_total);

end;
```

In the above program, value for the column total_emp is getting updated as 0 instead of numeric value.
However, when I use dbms_output statement to print the value, for both the cases, before and after , I'm getting the numeric value for the variable v_total.

v_total value is not getting updated to column value in table.

table column definition for total_emp is varchar2(20).

Also, I tried to hard code value for total_emp column in the above statement and it worked.

So, the problem is variable value when used in the update statement it's not getting updated to column.

Please help me.

Comment: "*total_emp is varchar2(20)*". Ouch!!! Do ***NOT*** store numbers in character columns. Never. Ever.

Comment: Is it being updated to zero, or was it already zero and is not being updated to the expected value? Do you actually have a row in `emp3` with `dept_no = 40` - was that where clause still there for your hard-coded-value version?

Answer (score 1):

The variables you declared should be of type NUMBER instead of VARCHAR2, as you intend to use them in calculations.  I also suggest you add an exception handler to report any errors which may occur.  It's also a good idea to show how many rows were affected by your update.  You might want to rewrite your code as:

```
Declare
  v_cnt NUMBER; 
  v_cnd NUMBER;
  v_total NUMBER;
begin
  select count(emp_id)
    into v_cnt
    from emp1;

  select count(emp_id)
    into v_cnd
    from emp2;

  v_total:=v_cnt+v_cnd;

  dbms_output.put_line('before');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_total);

  update emp3
    set total_emp=v_total
    where dept_no=40;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of rows updated=' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line('after');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_total);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || SQLCODE || '  ' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.